# Workflow Foundation 4, Problem when a change to a workflow is made?

Tags: workflow-foundation-4

right now we are starting working with Visual Studio 2010 and Windows Workflow Foundation 4 it has been pretty hard to work with but we are on it. My question is that we are wondering what happens in the instance store with records when a stored workflow code is change, we have seen that you can not continue with workflow instance we have to start a new one ?

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the features that didn't make it into WF4 was dynamic updates. That means there is no way to change the workflow definition of a running instance and have it continue. So you are basically left with with the option of running multiple version side by side, where you have to manage the versions or aborting existing instances and restarting them with the new worlflow definition.